Arcpy not reading SDE 10.8 DB contents
I'm trying to connect to our 10.8.1 Arc database via ArcPy.
I can connect to another external database that is running 10.2.. so there has to be some sort of versioning conflict, but I'm not sure what it is.
python version 2.7 
windows: 10.0.17763 Build 17763 (windows server 2019)
I do have ODBC Driver 18 64bit installed as I have read it needed version 17
Simple script
import arcpy
sde_connection_path = r"Database Connections\networks.sde"
arcpy.env.workspace = sde_connection_path

feature_classes = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses()
print("Feature Classes:", feature_classes)

Output:
('Feature Classes:', [])

